# Missing wysiwyg folder in magento

Tags: wysiwyg, media

When I try to upload some images on cms->pages in wysiwyg redactor I get an error

```
The directory is not writable by server.
```

I have already explored this error caused because of media->wysiwyg folder is missing. If I create this folder all will be fine. But I wonder why this folder is missing after installation magento. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have set the correct permissions for the folders upon installation?

Quoted from the [Magento installation guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_installation_guide):

> Ensure that the directories app/etc , var , and media are writable by the web server.

When the media directory has the correct permissions, the wysiwyg folder should be created automatically and thus the problem should be solved.